# How can we change the configuration information at runtime in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Config files are loaded in the start and I want to know where and how are they stored in the memory, because according to my understanding, files are loaded once and the information in them are stored in some variables, I want to know how can I change the values of those variables at run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you would change the value of any variable. Your config file will only tell the initial value of the variables you set to be loaded from it. Once the package starts you can manipulate the variables with a script task for example:

```
 Dts.Variables("YourVar").Value = True
```